# HTML, CSS: Input Box Goes Outside of Viewable Area

Tags: html, css

I have some divs and and input box.  When I resize the window, the divs adapt appropriately, but the input gets clipped.  How do I make the input resize to the screen size while having a max width of 400px?  Here are screenshots of the two states: [Looks good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1P5Id.jpg).  But when the page is narrowed the divs respond but [the input gets cut but the divs are good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5W7ch.jpg).

Here is how I styled my input

```
.text-input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: none;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px 1px #707070;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s;
  max-width: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.text-input:focus,
.text-input.focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px 1px #c9c9c9;
}
```

My question is, how should I style the input to make it behave the same as the divs?  Please also what is the intuition behind the solution?

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net), maybe?

Comment: How about putting the `input` with a `width` of `100%` inside a div?

Comment: I think your `width` and `max-width` are problematic of being used togetherly.

Comment: Try changing the input width to auto and/or add position relative on. If that doesn't work can you put you code in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `input` inside a `div`, give the `input` a `width:100%;`.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
    border: solid 1px red
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/98eewLcw/)

Comment: It looks like it renders outside the containing div when resized.  How would we stop that?

Comment: BTW, if I add margin (even on all sides!) the issue comes back.  So I wrapped it in a div, and set the div padding.  Is there a way to do that only with the input and not the auxiliary div? http://imgur.com/s133jyF

Comment: @DavidWilliams `border-box: The width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes content, padding and border, but not the margin`. Like they said, NOT THE MARGIN, but check this new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ph82qtmr/

Answer (score 1):

here is the fiddle

the problem was `width` was `100%` and `padding` was `xx px` so it comes to `100% + xxpx` thats the reason it was exceeding `100%`

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/32oy6npu/1/)

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

this property gives padding, border from inside which doesn't allow the width to exceed from 100%

Comment: This is also correct, and a really nice way of saying it, thanks, that gives me the intuition more.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove max-width from your code. Replace it with 100%.
If you want to be more web-responsive, you can define more deffinitions, each for different window size, like so:

```
@media screen and (max-width:720px) { width: 90%; }
@media screen and (min-width:720px) { width: 100%; }
```

Google responsive web design and screen width examples:)

Comment: I did that but now the input box doesn't terminate at the right side of the window http://imgur.com/QBR13z5  .  Ideas?